# What does it mean when a numeric constant in C/C++ is prefixed with a 0?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, syntax, numbers

Ok... So I had a silly idea and tried putting the value 0123 into an int, just curious to see what would happen, I assumed that when I printed the value I'd get 123, but instead I got 83... Any ideas why? what happens inside the compiler/memory that makes this value become 83?

I tried this in C++ and C with GCC compiler and also tried with a float which yielded the same results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In C/C++ a numeric literal prefixed with a '0' is octal (base 8).

See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/

Answer (score 8):

[Congratulations! You've discovered octal.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Integer-Constants)

Comment: Amusement is better than bemusement. :-)

Comment: `To write numbers in octal, precede the value with a 0. ...
To write numbers in octal, precede the value with a 0x or 0X. `  doh!

Comment: [D'oh!](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/hexoctal.html) is right!  Changed it for a better one... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is because any number starting with 0 like this is considered to be in octal (base 8) not decimal.

Same thing if you start with 0x you will get hexadecimal

Answer (score 3):

The leading 0 indicates an "octal" number. So it becomes 1*8^2 + 2*8^1 + 3*8^0 = 83

Comment: It's a leading `0` (zero), not a leading `O` (o).

Comment: Of course you are quite correct, just realised my mistake and came back to edit. Tempted to give myself a -1 for stupidity :-)

Answer (score 2):

0123 is an octal constant (base 8).  83 is the decimal equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`0123` is in [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ standard in **[lex.icon]** integer literals can be split in 3 types: decimal literals, octal literals and hexadecimal literals, each of which can have a suffix for signess and length type

Decimal literals **must** start with a nonzero digit, while octal literals start with 0 and hexadecimal literals have 0x and 0X, after the prefix (for octal-literals and hexadecimal-literals) any digit that is not representable in the corresponding base should trigger a compilation error (such as 09 that causes  `error C2041: illegal digit '9' for base '8'` and in other compiler `prog.cpp:6:15: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant`), since if the integer literal is not representable the program becomes ill-formed.