# Bitwise OR on Bitset giving wrong answer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset, std-bitset

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 bitset<5> num=01000;
 bitset<5> n=00000;
 bitset<5> result;
 result=(n|num);
 cout<<result;
}
```

Answer should be 1000
but it shows 00000

Comment: The values of both num and n will be 0, that's why the end result will be 0 too

Comment: Stop doing this: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and include the correct headers, i.e. `<bitset>` and `<iostream>`.

Comment: `01000` is not a 5-bit number, it's 0x200 or 512 in decimal [What does it mean when a numeric constant in C/C++ is prefixed with a 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6365565/995714), [printf with “%d” of numbers starting with 0 (ex “0102”) giving unexpected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19652583/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary literals have dedicated notion [(since C++14)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal): `0b01000` not `01000`.

```
#include <bitset>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::bitset<5> num = 0b01000;
    std::bitset<5> n = 0b00000;
    std::bitset<5> result;

    result = (n | num);

    std::cout << result << std::endl; // -> 01000

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Binary literals have different notion in C++14` there's no binary literals whatsoever prior to C++14. `01000` has always been octal

Comment: I mean exactly that.

Comment: what you wrote means that before C++ it has another notion which was wrong

Comment: My funny English...

Comment: btw, people tried to designate binary literals somehow even in [pre-C++14 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 1):

`01000` is an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) integer literal whose value is 512 with the 5 least significant bits being 0. Same to `00000`

Hence both `num` and `n` will be 0

To set the bitset to `01000` binary you can use

- `bitset<5> num("01000")`
- `bitset<5> num(0b01000)` using [C++14's binary integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)
- or just use `bitset<5> num(0x10)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign binary numbers then you can enclose them double quotes:

```
std::string binary_number = "1000";
std::bitset<5> num(binary_number);
std::bitset<5> n("0");
std::bitset<5> result;
result = (n | num);
std::cout << result;
```

but if you don't want to use enclose them in double quotes then you can do something like this:

```
std::bitset<5> num = 8;
std::bitset<5> n = 0;
std::bitset<5> result;
result = (n | num);
std::cout << result;
```