# Why is it that when I output an int with a leading zero it spits out a different number? How can I get rid of the leading zero? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, time, integer, leading-zero

For example, 0530 becomes 344 and if I output 0530%1000, it returns with 344.
You see, these four numbers are a time format (HHMM) and I am trying to read how many minutes passed since 0000, i.e the first two numbers times 60 plus the last two.

I tried looking for some int function manipulators but could not find any (maybe im bad at researching). I am looking for something like the opposite of setfill()

Comment: O, the joys of octal!

Comment: A literal integer with a leading zero is treated as octal. [What does it mean when a numeric constant in C/C++ is prefixed with a 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365565/what-does-it-mean-when-a-numeric-constant-in-c-c-is-prefixed-with-a-0)

Comment: An integral literal value with a leading zero, like `0530` is an *octal* value, not decimal.   So `0530` is equal (in decimal) to `5*8*8 + 3*8 + 0`, which is `344`.

Comment: Any [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or class or tutorial should have mentioned [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base-8) values together with hexadecimal.

Comment: Read a string, then extract the hours and minutes from that.